# Delete/Discard previously saved data from HealthKit

Tags: objective-c, ios8, healthkit

I'm developing an app that gives the users the option to track what they ate. One of the features the app suggest is to select a food item as `Eaten`. When a user does that, I share that info with the HealthKit.

A user can then decide to uncheck that item and return its previous state: `Uneaten`. I wonder if I can query the previously saved food item and choose to delete it from the HealthKit as it isn't relevant for the user anymore?

**UPDATE**

Well, After reading almost the entire documentation of HealthKit I found out that `HKHealthStore` object has a method: `deleteObject:withCompletion:`. Yet I can't seem to successfully delete an `HKCorrelation` that stores the food item I previously saved to HealthKit, though the call finish successfully (I can still see the data in the Health App)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `deleteObject:withCompletion:` API to delete the objects you saved.  If you saved an `HKCorrelation` you must delete each of the objects you saved with the correlation as well.

Comment: Can you please show an example of how to do this?  Thank you.

Comment: i provided an example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922734/deleting-a-water-sample-from-healthkit/38263174#38263174