# Deleting a Water Sample from HealthKit

Tags: healthkit

My application currently lets users save `WaterIntakeRecord`s and they are then persisted with Core Data. I am able to write to HealthKit, saving a water intake record as a `HKQuantitySample`.

I add a `WaterIntakeRecord` into my application with an amount of 12.9 fluid ounces. Since in Health, I have milliliters as my preferred unit of measurement, it shows in milliliters:

[image]

Where I am struggling is when trying to delete a sample.

When the user saves a `WaterIntakeRecord`, they can choose the unit of measurement that they want to save the sample in, and then it converts that measurement to US ounces, which is a property of `WaterIntakeRecord`. This way, every `WaterIntakeRecord` has a consistent unit of measurement that can be converted into other units of measurement (all the ones found in Health) for display.

When trying to delete a saved sample, I try this:

```
static func deleteWaterIntakeSampleWithAmount(amount: Double, date: NSDate) {

    guard let type = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryWater) else {
        print("———> Could not retrieve quantity type for identifier")
        return
    }

    let quantity = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.fluidOunceUSUnit(), doubleValue: amount)

    let sample = HKQuantitySample(type: type, quantity: quantity, startDate: date, endDate: date)

    HealthKitStore.deleteObject(sample) { (success, error) -> Void in
        if let err = error {
            print("———> Could not delete water intake sample from HealthKit: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("———> Deleted water intake sample from HealthKit")
        }
    }
}
```

When the user deletes a record in my application, it should delete the corresponding sample in HealthKit. The record is successfully deleted from my application, however, I keep getting an error when attempting to delete the sample from HealthKit, using the method above:

`Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=100 "Transaction failure." UserInfo {NSLocalizedDescription=Transaction failure.}`

I'm not sure what I am doing incorrectly to keep getting this error.

The `amount` parameter is the `WaterIntakeRecord`'s `ouncesUS` value, and the `date` parameter is the `WaterIntakeRecord`s `date` property which is the creation date of the record:

Any ideas on where I am causing the deletion to fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each sample in HealthKit is unique. When deleting a sample, you must first query for the sample that your app saved originally and then use it in your call to `HealthKitStore.deleteObject()`. In your code snippet above, you are creating a new, unsaved sample then attempting to delete it.

Comment: Thanks, Allan! I was able to rectify my situation by doing just what you suggested. I queried the HealthKit store and found the intended record to delete.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, a sample has to be queried and retrieved from health store before deletion. Below is the code i used in obj-c as a jump start for anyone new with this stuff:

```
// get an instance of the health store
self.healthStore = [[HKHealthStore alloc] init];

// the interval of the samples to delete (i observed that for a specific value if start and end date are equal the query doesn't return any objects)
NSDate *startDate = [dateOfSampleToDelete dateByAddingTimeInterval:0];
NSDate *endDate = [dateOfSampleToDelete dateByAddingTimeInterval:1];

// the type you're trying to delete (this could be heart-beats/steps/water/calories/etc..)
HKQuantityType *waterType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryWater];

// the predicate used to execute the query
NSPredicate *queryPredicate = [HKSampleQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate options:HKQueryOptionNone];

// prepare the query
HKSampleQuery *query = [[HKSampleQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:waterType predicate:queryPredicate limit:100 sortDescriptors:nil resultsHandler:^(HKSampleQuery * _Nonnull query, NSArray<__kindof HKSample *> * _Nullable results, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (error) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Successfully retreived samples");

        // now that we retrieved the samples, we can delete it/them
        [self.healthStore deleteObject:[results firstObject] withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {

            if (success) {

                NSLog(@"Successfully deleted entry from health kit");

            } else {

                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);

            }
        }];

    }
}];

// last but not least, execute the query
[self.healthStore executeQuery:query];
```

A better practice would be to check we indeed have an object to delete before executing the `[results firstObject]` part of the above solution