# Removing water sample from HealthKit on Apple Watch

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2, healthkit

We are making water tracking app where user can add water samples. Data is added to Health directly from Apple Watch and iPhone apps. One of the features is undo.

I am trying to remove water samples from Apple Watch and it works fine. However if I add the sample on iPhone and will remove it from the Apple Watch, the sample is not removed. The worst part, I am not getting any error, HealthKit callback returns success.

```
- (void)removeSampleWithCompletion:(void (^ _Nonnull)(bool success, NSError *_Nullable error))completion {

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *startDate = [calendar startOfDayForDate:myDate];

    // the type you're trying to delete (this could be heart-beats/steps/water/calories/etc..)
    HKQuantityType *waterType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryWater];

    // the predicate used to execute the query
    NSPredicate *queryPredicate = [HKSampleQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:startDate
                                                                          endDate:myDate
                                                                          options:HKQueryOptionStrictEndDate];

    // prepare the query
    HKSampleQuery *query = [[HKSampleQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:waterType
                                                           predicate:queryPredicate
                                                               limit:100
                                                     sortDescriptors:nil
                                                      resultsHandler:^(HKSampleQuery * _Nonnull query, NSArray<__kindof HKSample *> * _Nullable results, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                                                          if (!error) {
                                                              // Successfully retreived samples

                                                              // Filter only our samples. It is no possible to delete others.
                                                              NSMutableArray <HKSample *>*locassaSamples = [NSMutableArray new];
                                                              for (HKSample *sample in results) {
                                                                  if ([sample.sourceRevision.source.bundleIdentifier isEqual:@"com.companyname.appname"]) {
                                                                      [locassaSamples addObject:sample];
                                                                  }
                                                              }

                                                              // Remove last
                                                              HKSample *theLast = locassaSamples.lastObject;

                                                              if (theLast == nil) {
                                                                  return;
                                                              }

                                                              [self.healthStore deleteObject:theLast
                                                                         withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                                                                                  completion(success, error);
                                                                         }];

                                                              return;


                                                          } else {
                                                              completion(FALSE, error);
                                                          }
                                                      }];
    // Source http://stackoverflow.com/a/38263174/1162044

    // last but not least, execute the query
    [self.healthStore executeQuery:query];
}
```

Update.
I created a radar [#28007271](https://openradar.appspot.com/28007271).

Comment: Where do you notice the sample still after deleting it? The phone or the watch?

Comment: They stay in the Health app on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue that is fixed in iOS 10 and watchOS 3.

Comment: Thank you. I will make sure it works for me on iOS 10 and will accept this later.